# How to create dynamic incrementing variable using “for” loop in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic

How to create dynamic incrementing variable using "for" loop in C#? like this: 
`track_1, track_2, track_3, track_4.` so on.

Comment: Mind posting some code what of you've already done/tried?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 8):

You can't create dynamically-named variables. All you can do - it to create some collection or array, and operate with it.
I think the best class for you is generic [List<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

```
List<String> listWithDynamic = new List<String>();
for (int i = 1; i < limit; i +=1)
{
    listWithDynamic.Add(string.Format("track_{0}", i));
    ...
}
```

Comment: if it's in a for loop he might know the count up front making an array possible

Comment: @Rune FS according the OP's `and so on` I thought that he don't know the `.Count`

Comment: yes it's possible to change the number of iterations of a for loop inside the loop but it's uncommon if he knows the number of iterations. I would assume he knows the number of objects he needs. However all that is of course only assumptions and if any of the are wrong he''l have to use List<T> or something similar

Comment: You can, even with just a local variable.

Comment: @Jonathan Dickinson Really? Create variable with dynamic **name**? Can you show some code?

Comment: @Jonathan Dickinson The solution you've provided will generate dynamic **strings**, not dynamic-named variables.

Comment: @VMAtm downvote removed, however, his question is ambiguous. Could you clarify the "You can't." bit? "You can't create dynamically-named variables."

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want strings:

```
for (int i = 1; i < limit; i +=1)
{
    string track = string.Format("track_{0}", i);
    ...
}
```

But when you already have variables called `track_1, track_2, track_3, track_4` you will need an array or List:

```
var tracks = new TrackType[] { track_1, track_2, track_3, track_4 } ;

for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++)
{
    var track = tracks[i];  // tracks[0] == track_1
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to generate the variable name dynamically, like it is possible in some dynamically typed languages.

Comment: +1 for figuring out that he might not be talking about strings.

Answer (score 1):

**Obvious Solution**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var track = string.Format("track_{0}", i);

}
```

**Linq-Based Solution**

```
foreach (var track in Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => string.Format("track_{0}", x)))
{

}
```

**Operator-Based Solution** *This is somewhat hacky, but fun none-the-less.*

```
for (var i = new Frob(0, "track_{0}"); i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.ValueDescription);
}

struct Frob
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public string ValueDescription { get; private set; }
    private string _format;

    public Frob(int value, string format)
        : this()
    {
        Value = value;
        ValueDescription = string.Format(format, value);
        _format = format;
    }

    public static Frob operator ++(Frob value)
    {
        return new Frob(value.Value + 1, value._format);
    }

    public static Frob operator --(Frob value)
    {
        return new Frob(value.Value - 1, value._format);
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Frob value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Frob value)
    {
        return value.ValueDescription;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Frob)
        {
            return ((Frob)obj).Value == Value;
        }
        else if (obj is string)
        {
            return ((string)obj) == ValueDescription;
        }
        else if (obj is int)
        {
            return ((int)obj) == Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ValueDescription;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know if I get your question, but I will try:

```
for(var i = 1; i < yourExclusiveUpperbound; i++)
{
   var track = String.Format("$track_{0}", i);
   // use track
}
```

or with some LINQ-Magic:

```
foreach(var track in Enumerate.Range(1, count)
                              .Select(i => String.Format("$track_{0}", i)))
{
   // use track
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as follow:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i ++)
{
    any work do in loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't create dynamically named variables in a loop. But, there are other elegant ways to address the problem instead of creating dynamically named variables.

One could be, create an array or list before the loop and store values in array / list items in the loop. You can access the array / list later anywhere in your code. If you know which variable you want to use (track_1, track_2, ...), you can simply access it from the array / list (tracks[1], tracks[2], ...).

```
List<String> tracks = new List<String>();
for (int i = 1; i < limit; i++)
{
    Track track = new Track();
    tracks.Add(track);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (int i=5;i<30;(i%2==0)?i=i+4:i=i+2) {
     cout<<i;
     cout<<endl;
   }
```

Using ternary operator can help.

Comment: `cout` doesn't seem like C# to me